# Download a web page with its dependencies using javaScript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing an extension for Google Chrome. And i need to download a user focused web page with its dependencies (.php, .css ,.js ...etc) when user clicks a button on popup .html file. So far i came up with this below code which download the current html file.

```
var url;
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
 url = tabs[0].url;
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click", function () {
    chrome.downloads.download({         
      "url": url,
       saveAs: true
    }, function () {
        console.log("downloaded Complete");
    });
});
});
```

'download' is a button i  have in the popup.html file. (which used for the browser action popup)

How can i modify this code to download web page with its dependencies ?

Comment: Although you said PHP file, are you aware that you will not obtain the source code right?

Comment: @Rubens Mariuzzo : actually what i need is to do is save the web page for use it in the  offline mode. So then it can be view with its css and images as well. That is when we download a web page using `save as` option it will  download all the dependencies. that is the exact thing i need to do.

Comment: although here it opens a saveAs window it will not save the whole page. If someone know how to do that it will be very helpful.